# How to show any div if any specific div have specific image

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am working on below task but cant do it.

if i have smiley.png in div.selected

```
   <div class="selected" style=""><img width="25" height="24"  src="images/smileys/smiley.png" icon-value="1" icon-index="0"></div>
```

then on hover of div.selected-icon show the div.show-hover otherwise display it none

```
 <div class="selected-icon" style=""><img width="25" height="24" src="images/smileys/smiley.png"></div>

 <div class="show-hover">xyz</div>
```

any help??

Comment: couldn't understand what are you trying to say?

Comment: i am trying to say if i have 1.png in the div having class="one" then on hover of div having class="two" how can i show div with class="Three"

Comment: think your looking for some CSS `.selected {display:none;} .selected:hover {display:block;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<div id="flip">Hover to show the panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

CSS

```
#panel, #flip
{
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#e5eecc;
    border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel
{
    padding:50px;
    display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#flip").mouseover(function(){
        $("#panel").show();
    });

    $("#flip").mouseout(function(){
        $("#panel").hide();
    });   

});
```

or another js for slide effect

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DhYXH/)

Answer (score 3):

try this

**jQuery**

```
$('.selected-icon').mouseover(function()
{
    $('.show-hover').show();
});
$('.selected-icon').mouseout(function()
{
    $('.show-hover').hide();
});
```

**HTML code**

```
 <div class="selected-icon" style=""><img width="25" height="24" src="images/smileys/smiley.png"></div>

 <div class="show-hover" style="display:none">xyz</div>
```

see [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/boopathirajan/qD8Zb/)

Comment: HUH? @Boopathi U posted answer to the wrong question, I guess. LOL

Comment: `A wild answer appears!`

Comment: @Anup now see my answer

Comment: Yes seen...but no image seen.

Comment: yes, http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/800px-Smiley.svg.png give this img location in demo

Answer (score 3):

So you want to show a sibling on hover?

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GapVQ/)

```
.show-hover {
    display: none;
}

.selected-icon:hover + .show-hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use onmouseover and onmouseout to change the display css value via javascript of the elements you want to show/hide.

```
<div class="selected" style="" onmouseover="javascript:document.getElementById('selected-icon').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('show-hover').style.display = 'block';" onmouseout="javascript:document.getElementById('selected-icon').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('show-hover').style.display = 'none';"><img width="25" height="24"  src="images/smileys/smiley.png" icon-value="1" icon-index="0"></div>

<div class="selected-icon" id="selected-icon" style="display: none;"><img width="25" height="24" src="images/smileys/smiley.png"></div>

<div class="show-hover" id="show-hover" style="display: none;">xyz</div>
```